# Faster way to perform function calculation in Python?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.4

I'm interested in whether there is a way to further improve a "fast" version of a function used in a homework assignment I received recently (I've already submitted the completed work).

```
from math import log

def func_fast(mass, density):
    return sum(map((log(mass * density)).__truediv__, range(1,10001)))

def func_slow(mass, density): 
    total = 0.0 
    for i in range(10000): 
        masslog = log(mass * density) 
        total += masslog/(i+1)

    return total

mass = 2.5 
density = 12.0
```

The fast version times in around 2-2.5ish seconds while the slow version nets 6-7 seconds.

Comment: total += log(mass*density)/(i+1) might shave off a few milliseconds, but nothing really notable.

Comment: A lot more noteable will it be if you just move the `log` calculation out of the loop (which is effectively what the `func_fast` function is doing differently) ...

Comment: Actually, if I do what I wrote here (have `log(mass*density)` precalculated), the "slow" function is about 20% faster than the "fast" one.

Comment: This question has been reposted on Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/76978/faster-way-to-perform-function-calculation-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

def func_faster(mass, density):
    return (log(mass*density) / np.arange(1, 10001)).sum()
```

This is 10 times faster on my machine.

Comment: I can't use numpy since it's an external module. :)